# e-signature + digital signature aws md5

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, aws

I am trying to implement e-signature + digital signature to secure the e-signed document from altered, something like Docusign. I am using AWS s3 to store the documents.

My question are:

1. Is MD5 (checksum) enough to track if the signed document is altered? or I need Sha256?
2. Every time when the file is uploaded to etag (MD5) checksum is generated automatically, Can I use this value to verified if the document is altered?

Comment: *"to secure the e-signed document"* - If the document is already signed, you just verify the signature. Why are you looking for something else?

Comment: See [the evil developer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70057/18298) and [some other examples](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87104/18298)

Answer (score 0):

> Is MD5 (checksum) enough to track if the signed document is altered?

MD5 is a weak hash vulnerable to practical collision attacks, i.e. an attacker could create two different documents with the same MD5. This means that you cannot not use MD5 to detect if a document was altered if your (unknown) threat vector includes an attacker trying to bypass your detection.

> I need Sha256?

Sha256 is considered safe against such attacks.